# how to use List on Redis developing with C++ using hiredis

Tags: c++, linux, redis, hiredis

I try to use list with redis on Linux with C++ , how to use "rpush", "lpush", "rpop", "lpop" on C++？
I wrote like these:

```
this->_reply = (redisReply *) redisCommand(this->_context, "LPUSH %s %s", key.c_str(), value.c_str());
this->_reply = (redisReply *) redisCommand(this->_context, "RPOP %s", key.c_str());
```

But it doesn't success, and the "this->_reply->str" said "WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value"

How can I use these methods? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you have previously added that same  key to your redis instance as something other than a list ?

Comment: @nos After I using "DEL key" to delete the key, run it again and have an Error said "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what():basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid" what should I do next？

Comment: @Gerhardh sorry I forgot it and already deleted it

Comment: Next you need to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can debug and fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

`WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value` means the what the key hold is not a list, so when you want to do a lpush on this key, it complains about it.

You could use `TYPE key` command to test the key's type with redis-cli first.